# Assigning a customized event to an Objects OnMouseEnter event

Tags: delphi

I am looking for a way to reroute the event handler for `OnMouseEnter` of TPanel. I have a class that contains an array of TPanels that I am using to represent a seating chart. I would like to be able to assign a custom event to the `OnMouseEnter` event of each of the TPanels which are created dynamically at runtime. I will provide some pseudo code to try and help clarify:

```
//Class Declaration

TMyClass = Class(TObject)
 PanelArray : Array of TPanel;
end

//Forms declarations

MyClass : TMyClass //Created on the on create event of form.

//Loop assigning the new event
For I:=0 To High(MyClass.PanelArray) do
Begin
  //Instance of panel
  MyClass.PanelArray[I].OnMouseEnter := NewOnMouseEnterEvent(Parm1,Parm2,Parm3,....ParmN);
end;
```

When New `OnMouseEnter` event is called, in place of TPanel's `OnMouseEnter` I imagine it would function exactly the way it would if you had placed a panel on a form at design time and created an `OnMouseEnter` event from the object Inspector, but with the ability to pass additional parameters:

```
TForm1.Panel1OnMouseEnter(Sender: Tobject; Parm1,Parm2,Parm3,....ParmN:String);
begin
  ShowMessage(Parm1);
end;
```

Can anyone suggest a possible solution to this? I hope I was clear enough, I am a first time poster. Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `OnMouseEnter` property has type `TNotifyEvent`, which is a method pointer that expects exactly one parameter. You cannot assign pointers to other methods with other signatures.

The parameter you get is `Sender`, which is technically all you need. That tells you which panel is being acted on. Using that, you can look up whatever other values you need that should be associated with that panel. For example, you could define a record that holds all your other parameters, and then store them in a dictionary keyed off the panels:

```
type
  TMouseEnterParameters = record
    Param1, Param2, ..., ParamN: string;
  end;

  TMouseEnterDictionary = TDictionary<TPanel, TMouseEnterParameters>;
```

Populate the dictionary when you assign the event handlers:

```
for i := 0 to High(MyClass.PanelArray) do begin
  MyClass.PanelArray[i].OnMouseEnter := Panel1OnMouseEnter;
  ParamDict[MyClass.PanelArray[i]] := MakeParameters(Param1, Param2, ..., ParamN);
end;
```

Then you can find the associated values in the `OnMouseEnter` hander:

```
Params := ParamDict[Sender as TPanel];
```

If you Delphi version is too old to support a generic `TDictionary` class, you can use any number of other data structures, too. `TDictionary` just makes it easy.

Comment: Thank you very much for your timely response. I have never worked with the Data Type TDictionary, so I will have to research it and find out if my version of Delphi supports that class.

Comment: I just have a few questions, I assume Params is of type TMouseEnterParamaters? I have no Panel1OnMouseEnter, I was using that as an example, since I have no design time panels, will Class Procedure OnMouseEnter, assigned to each OnMouseEnter for the created panels suffice? I assume each Sender of each created panel is unique and that's how it links itself to the correct object stored in the TDictionary?

Comment: Yes, it's the same type as the value type in the dictionary. The Sender parameter indicates the object whose event was fired, so it's obviously unique among your group of panels. If you don't have a method to handle the events, then declare one, just like the IDE does when you double-click on an event property.

Comment: I checked and unfortunately TDictionary was introduced in Delphi 2009, I am using 2007. However I did use some of the logic behind your answer to arrive at a test solution. If I post my code would you be willing to look at it and give me some feedback? I will accept your answer either way. Looking forward to hearing back from you. Thanks again.

Comment: I guess I could do that, sure. Post your code at [codereview.se].

Comment: I will when I get into work on Monday. Thank you very much for all your helpful support.

Comment: I have posted my code on code review. I have posted the link for your convenience. Let me know if you have any questions. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/26102/suggestions-for-improvement-handling-mouseenter-mouseleave-events-for-dynamic